# Corte de papel (acionar guilhotina) impressora térmica Diebold pelo PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Estou finalizando uma solução, porém estou empacado na hora de cortar o papel, não consigo acionar a guilhotina.

Tentei de várias formas, tais como `$faca = chr(dechex(15));` e mais `$faca = chr(27).chr(109);` e assim por diante nesta mesma linha de pensamento escrevendo no php, porém estes caracteres não são reconhecidos.

Alguém teria alguma ideia de como fazê-lo? Tanto pelo PHP ou Javascript.

Agradeço.

Comment: Parece que está misturando as linguagens, no PHP, o `.` é usado para concatenar strings

Comment: Não estou misturando, estou mostrando os caracteres que envio para o arquivo texto que não é interpretado pela impressora, estes caracteres no fim do arquivo deveriam acionar a guilhotina.